# Exact format of a open ssh private key

Tags: ssh, rsa, private-key, openssh, ctf

I've been trying to complete a CTF on HackTheBox and at some point I get a openssh private key that I can then use to connect as root through ssh.
The command I use is "ssh -i id_rsa root@<IP_ADDRESS>" by the way but I'm almost sure that's not the issue.
The thing is I get this private key under pdf format and I've been trying a lot of stuff to create a file id_rsa from it but everytime I get this reply from ssh :
load pubkey "id_rsa": invalid format
Load key "id_rsa": invalid format
So I don't know where the problem comes from, if it's a matter of space or ..
The file I create (id_rsa) has no extension.
Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You would probably need to create a .pub file with the pdf content. And if needed give the right permission for usage `chmod 600 file`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did the chmod part, the thing is the key I have is a private one and thats what I need for my ssh connection

Comment: Think this thread could help you more: https://superuser.com/questions/1370877/ssh-error-loading-key-id-rsa-invalid-format